# Call a method in a class

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that defines a class of 2x2 matrices. I have then made a method that can calculate the determinant of a 2x2 matrix by defining:

```
double Matrix2x2::CalcDeterminant() const
{
return val00*val11-val10*val01; //these are the values of the matrix entries
}
```

Now if I want to test this on some instance (I am not sure if this is the right word) of the class I have tried to write:

```
int main()
{
Matrix2x2 A=Matrix2x2::Matrix2x2(1,2,3,4); // Matrix2x2 is a constructor that takes 4 real numbers as input and returns a 2x2 matrix

Matrix2x2::CalcDeterminant(A); //this is where my coding fails. What is wrong with this line?
}
```

But the code fails on the last line, which is apparently not the correct way of calling the method. What am I doing wrong? I am very new to all this.

Comment: off topic: Rather than 4 different `valXX` variables, may I recommend a singular `double val[2][2];`? A second possibility, `std::array<std::array<double,2>,2> val;`, is a lot uglier, but often a lot easier to pass to other functions and objects.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
int main() {
    Matrix2x2 A(1,2,3,4);

    double det = A.CalcDeterminant();
}
```

Here we create a `Matrix2x2` object called `A` using the constructor you mentioned, and call `CalcDeterminant` on `A` (i.e. the instance of the `Matrix2x2` we just created). The code you provided would work if `CalcDeterminant` was a `static` method and took an argument of type `Matrix2x2`.

Answer (score 1):

Each member function in C++ has a special argument, known as `this`. You don't need to explicitly pass it, like you do. The `this` argument is somewhat like the `FILE *` argument of the `stdio.h` functions. It provides a handle to this instance of the class.

Member function calls follow the form

```
inst.func(args);
```

So in your case, you can call

```
A.CalcDeterminant();
```

The only time you write `classname::func(args)` is if `func` is a `static` member function. These kinds of functions do not have a `this` pointer; that is, they cannot access any of the containing class' members. For example,

```
class time {
    // some private members
public:
    // other members
    static time now();
};
```

The `now` function obtains the current time. It makes sense to make `now` be static, since it doesn't use any of `time`'s members. `now` would be called like this

```
time::now();
```

I recommend *The C++ Programming Language*.

Answer (score 0):

This is elementary C++ syntax:

```
int main() {
  Matrix2x2 A(1,2,3,4);
  A.CalcDeterminant();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is for static methods. Your method is not static, so you need to apply th method to your object:

```
A.CalcDeterminant();
```